# Several Problems with Google SDK Speech-to-text (Transcription) details

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've encountered several fairly serious problems in my efforts to develop a speech-to-text application. Some of them (I hope) may just be my lack of experience/common-sense/in-depth-reading/etc. Here's the list:

1. Long (>60 sec) transcriptions -- Forces me to use a GS bucket to first upload the soundfile to the bucket. Trouble is:
   a. I have to run the "gcloud auth login" on each machine I need to run on. I have well over 50 machines. This appears to be a purely manual operation, as you have to copy a long URL to your  browser, hit enter, click on the right account, accept the permissions, then hand-copy and paste the key presented back into the gcloud prompt, and hit enter there. While it does appear to be presistent to some degree, it is subject to one interesting constraint: only 51 machines (maybe 50, I got tired trying to count) are allowed. And the earliest logged-in machine is un-loggedin to make room for the new login. This was very odious. All this hassle is purely for using the buckets.  A shorter transcription will not use GS, and complete without complaint. Really!!!! Is there no better way? Do we have to use gcloud auth login? Manually????  The number of servers we can use with GoogleStorage????
2. Another google storage issue: transcription requires the bucket to be "public". We are pretty worried about security, and the privacy of our  customers, whose recordings will be in the uploaded bucket, even if only there briefly.
3. The transcription app offers transcriptions in multiple languages, but the "phone_call" model is fixed to en_US, and seems to ignore the language setting. If I change the request to es_US, and supply a spanish recording, it behaves the same. (But everything works OK in the 'command_and_search' model). This seems to be in evolution, any idea when/if they will carry the multi-language features over to the phone_call model?

If anyone can help, Oh Wise Ones, please impart of thy wisdom!

murf

Comment: Hi, from what I understand, you have 50 machine and they upload voice transcript to GS bucket, is that correct? Are these GCP VM or 50 actual physical machine?

I think there is maximum # of connection a gs bucket can take.

I see you use gcloud auth login command, have you tried to use gsutil? [1] 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

Comment: ad 1) you can use Signed URLs for this purpose: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#overview